# Can not use $php_errormsg on xampp server

Tags: php

Whenever I am trying to use `$php_errormsg` to output errors, it says

> Undefined variable:php_errormsg in ......

I have already set `track_errors=on` in php.ini
file.
I guess the error should be generated in function call and php_errormsg should contain it.
What may be the possible causes and solution ?

```
function fun($x,$y){
   echo "function called";
}
@fun(3);
echo $php_errormsg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From php.net manual:

> `$php_errormsg` is a variable containing the text of the last error
>   message generated by PHP. This variable will **only be available within
>   the scope in which the error occurred**, and only if the track_errors
>   configuration option is turned on (it defaults to off).

I guess you are trying to access the variable not inside the same scope (in a function or class or method for example) as the scope the error was generated in.

Also, when there was no error, the variable would not exist.

As you updated the question, my assumption was correct:

```
function fun($x,$y){
   // error generated in function scope, e.g. unknown function:
   i_dont_exist($x);
   echo "function called";
}
@fun(3);
// error not available in global scope, only inside `fun`
echo $php_errormsg;
```

If you want a global, super error handler, use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler).

Comment: First of all thanks for help.I have edited the question with code.I guess the error should be in scope.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Got it.I was thinking that the error should be generated before the body of function executes,that is during the function call only, so error should be in global scope.

Comment: @KrrishRaj You should really look into `set_error_handler();`, it works globally.

Answer (score 0):

The correct name of the variable would be `$php_errormsg`. You could use `echo $php_errormsg;` to display it

Comment: This is exactly how OP spelled it.

Comment: If the missing `$` sign was not a typo in OP, the error message would probably have been about an undefined constant.

Comment: why should he remove the $ before posting it to SO? Therefore it'S not the same...

Comment: The error message, when you forget the `$` is: `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant php_errormsg - assumed 'php_errormsg'`